# What's the less expensive way to find missing records for this table structure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, lookup, missing-data

I've got a main data stream table with a format similar to *Stream Table* below. Each **idtype** has got a set of possible **idname**.

I'm trying to find out which **id** has got missing **idname**. I've also created a table which contains all the **idtype** and their **idname** values as shown in the *Stream Info Table*.

I'm flexible around the solution to look these values up, it's not a fixed lookup table, but I'll need to know which one was missing and the id and not just the number of missing values.

```
Stream Table
╔════╦═════════════════════════╦══════════╦════════╦═══════════╗
║ id ║       idtimestamp       ║  idtype  ║ idname ║  idvalue  ║
╠════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║ 2020-05-15 10:49:58.773 ║ external ║ body   ║ round     ║
║  1 ║ 2020-05-15 10:49:58.773 ║ external ║ genre  ║ all       ║
║  1 ║ 2020-05-15 10:49:58.773 ║ external ║ size   ║ uniform   ║
║  2 ║ 2020-05-15 10:49:58.773 ║ internal ║ batch  ║ batchname ║
║  2 ║ 2020-05-15 10:49:58.773 ║ internal ║ link   ║ quad      ║
╚════╩═════════════════════════╩══════════╩════════╩═══════════╝

Stream Info Table
╔══════════╦════════╗
║  idtype  ║ idname ║
╠══════════╬════════╣
║ external ║ blue   ║
║ external ║ body   ║
║ external ║ genre  ║
║ external ║ size   ║
║ internal ║ batch  ║
║ internal ║ link   ║
║ internal ║ whyte  ║
╚══════════╩════════╝
```

For the given set of data I'm expecting to output this data:

```
╔════╦═════════════════════════╦══════════╦════════╦
║ id ║       idtimestamp       ║  idtype  ║ idname ║  
╠════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════╬════════╬
║  1 ║ 2020-05-14 20:48:50.540 ║ external ║ blue   ║ 
║  2 ║ 2020-05-14 20:48:50.540 ║ internal ║ whyte  ║  
╚════╩═════════════════════════╩══════════╩════════╩
```

Example dataset:

```
drop table if exists #stream_data
create table #stream_data (id int, idtimestamp datetime, idtype varchar(30), idname varchar(60), idvalue varchar(100))
insert into #stream_data
select '1' , getdate() , 'external' , 'body' , 'round' union
select '1' , getdate() , 'external' , 'size' , 'uniform' union
select '1' , getdate() , 'external' , 'genre' , 'all' union
select '2' , getdate() , 'internal' , 'batch' , 'batchname' union
select '2' , getdate() , 'internal' , 'link' , 'quad' 


drop table if exists #stream_info 
create table #stream_info (idtype varchar(30), idname varchar(60))
insert into #stream_info
select 'external' , 'body' union
select 'external' , 'size' union
select 'external' , 'genre' union
select 'external' , 'blue' union
select 'internal' , 'batch' union 
select 'internal' , 'link' union
select 'internal' , 'whyte'
```

Comment: What was your attempt and what about it made you think it was expensive?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Comment: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)

Comment: @philipxy appreciate your thoughtful comment. However, I'm not looking for an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) scenario here. I've posted what I'm trying to achieve and I'm open to suggestions from other engineers which is the underlying principle of stackoverflow.

Comment: My comments have nothing to do with XY questions. [help]

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
select *
from #stream_data sd
where not exists
(
  select *
  from #stream_info si
  where si.idtype = sd.idtype
    and si.idname = sd.idname
)
```

outputs

```
id  idtimestamp             idtype     idname  idvalue
--- ----------------------- ---------- ------- -----------
1   2020-05-14 15:17:20.487 external   batch   batchname
2   2020-05-14 15:17:20.487 internal   float   whyte
```

Comment: Apologies, I've messed up the data. It's the other way around, #stream_info has got more information than #stream_data. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE     @StreamData TABLE   (id int, idtimestamp datetime, idtype varchar(30), idname varchar(60), idvalue varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @StreamData VALUES
            ('1' , getdate() , 'external' , 'body'  , 'round'       )
        ,   ('1' , getdate() , 'external' , 'genre' , 'all'         )
        ,   ('1' , getdate() , 'external' , 'size'  , 'uniform'     )
        ,   ('2' , getdate() , 'internal' , 'batch' , 'batchname'   )
        ,   ('2' , getdate() , 'internal' , 'link'  , 'quad'        )

DECLARE     @StreamInfo TABLE   (idtype varchar(30), idname varchar(60))
INSERT INTO @StreamInfo VALUES
            ('external' , 'blue'    )
        ,   ('external' , 'body'    )
        ,   ('external' , 'genre'   )
        ,   ('external' , 'size'    )
        ,   ('internal' , 'batch'   )
        ,   ('internal' , 'link'    )
        ,   ('internal' , 'whyte'    )

-- With LEFT JOIN you are getting all of the rows of the StreamInfo Table
-- With the WHERE Clause you are just getting those without a matching row in the StreamData Table
SELECT  SI.*
FROM           @StreamInfo SI
    LEFT JOIN  @StreamData SD   ON  SD.idtype   =   SI.idtype
                                AND SI.idname   =   SD.idname
WHERE           SD.idname IS NULL
```

Comment: sorry - I've messed up the data. The looking up goes the other way around, I'm trying to find out if there are any missing records in #stream_table by looking into #stream_info. Updated the question.